# C#: Iterating through a data table: Rows, Select() or AsEnumerable()

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Select())

foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable())

foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
```

Any differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Rows` isn't strongly typed - so there will be a cast on each iteration, and you can't use LINQ to objects on it easily. (I believe `AsEnumerable()` will have to cast on each iteration internally as well, but at least you can use it for other LINQ methods easily.)

`Select` needs to build an array, so there's obviously a performance penalty there.

Personally I'd use `AsEnumerable()` unless you wanted to modify the table within the loop, in which case the fact that `Select` builds an array up-front may actually be an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsEnumerable() if you are trying to query the datatable using LINQ, otherwise, you might as well use the looping structure...